# Curvature of a curve projected on its osculator plan

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

I have to prove that for any regular curve in $\mathbb{R^3}$ it's curvature $k(t)$ is the same as the curvature of its projection on the osculator plane at $t$

Basically what i did was writting on the canonical local form, and projecting on the First two coordinates, deriving twice and taking the norm, but it lead me nowhere
I get $\sqrt{({ks^2})^2+(k+sk')^2}$ if i dont carry the aproximation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Taylor expansion at point $t_0$, you will get something like that

$$
\mathbf{r}(t) = \mathbf{r}(t_0) + \mathbf{r'}(t_0)\Delta t + \mathbf{r''}(t_0)\frac{\Delta t^2}2 + \mathbf{O}(\Delta t^3)
$$

Then you show that vectors $\mathbf{r'}(t_0)$ and $\mathbf{r''}(t_0)$ lie on the osculating plane. That leads to the expansion of the projection curve $\mathbf{\tilde r}(t)$:

$$
\mathbf{\tilde r}(t) = \mathbf{r}(t_0) + \mathbf{r'}(t_0)\Delta t + \mathbf{r''}(t_0)\frac{\Delta t^2}2 + \mathbf{O}(\Delta t^3)
$$

So $\mathbf{r}(t)$ and $\mathbf{\tilde r}(t)$ share first three terms of expansions. Finally, you know that curvature depends only on first and second derivatives.

Comment: But the two curves have different speeds, in general, so you have to be a *tiny* bit careful in that "depends only on" statement.